# How to copy content of one EditText to another with spans?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have two editText and I want to copy/move the content of one editText to another along with the spans.

I have tried doing `edittext1.append(edittext2.getText());` but the copied text then loses the spans applied.

- How can I do that in android?
- suppose my two edittexts are `edittext1` and `edittext2`.

Comment: what spans are you applying to edittext2 in the first place? are they fixed or determined at runtime by the user?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331579/how-to-copy-a-text-from-a-edittext-to-another-edittext-by-button-clicking-in-and

Comment: @OMiShah that doesn't mention spans as far as I could tell

Comment: @OMiShah i am concerned with spans at the moment, the question you referred does simply copy .

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I am appying spans like BoldSpan(), ItalicSpan() ...

Comment: not sure if there's a method that would append the two strings but respect the individual spans, but if you know the spans you want to use each time, you could first append the strings, then apply the spans with an index that begins on the first character of the text originally found in edittext2 and ends on the last character of the same text

Answer (score 1):

Use getSpans method of Editable to retrieve spans from first EditText. In for loop apply this spans (with setSpan method) to second EditText

Comment: i know this one, but i was actually looking for a more precise approach.
thanks for you solution.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment above, even though it might not be the optimal solution, I think the following steps should work:

You save the length of the text in edittext1. This will be the index of where the text of edittext2 is getting appended.

```
int startIndex = edittext1.getText().length();
```

You check the length of the text in edittext2 and add it to the length of edittext1. This is where the text will end once you append.

```
int endIndex = edittext2.getText().length( ) + startIndex - 1;
```

You append the text as you mention in your example
and you create your desired spans

```
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
int flag = Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE;
```

You apply the spans to edittext1 which now includes the appended text.

```
edittext1.getText().setSpan(boldSpan, startIndex, endIndex, flag);
```